# How to import the module in python by overriding the builtin modules

Tags: python

How to import a module which we have created in python.

Example
I have created the math module in python but when I'm importing by using
import math
Then it's importing the math module from Standard libraries which I don't require
I have tried importing by giving
from my_location import math
But didn't work

So please any suggestions how to import our modules by overriding the built-in module??

Comment: **Don't** do that. Give your module a non-built-in name

Comment: I agree with @DeepSpace

Comment: I also agree, but still, if you simply put that file in the same directory of your `math` module than it will be imported and ***not*** the built-in one...

Answer (score 1):

You can use importlib.import_module to manually import modules, assuming your module is in your PYTHONPATH:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

However, as other people have said, it is a very bad idea to override the names of python standard library modules. You should use a different name when you import and ideally rename your module entirely to something other than math.